# html5 canvas copy imageData to tmpcanvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

i create an apps in HTML5 canvas, for cropping image. there are 3 canvases in the DOM, one for drawing the line, one for original image, and another one for the result.

and here is the code i use.

```
// copy image data to secondary canvas
var pixelData = ctx.getImageData(x-10, y-10, 20, 20);
var tmpCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
tmpCanvas.width = 20; tmpCanvas.height = 20;
var tmpCtx = tmpCanvas.getContext("2d");
tmpCtx.putImageData(pixelData, x, y);
var tmpImageEl = document.createElement("img");
tmpImageEl.onload = function(){
    ctxCopy.drawImage(this, x, y);
}
console.log(tmpCanvas.toDataURL());
tmpImageEl.src = tmpCanvas.toDataURL();
//ctxCopy.putImageData(pixelData, x, y);

//document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(tmpCanvas);
```

in this line

```
tmpImageEl.src = tmpCanvas.toDataURL();
```

i got nothing but blank/transparent image. what i expect is the imagedata from original source..what is wrong with the code? if there is rounded options for putImageData this could be easier for me (i aleady googling about rounded putImageData, no luck)

Comment: maybe you could clarify the code sample so we clearly see the 3 canvases and the worflow. What is ctxCopy ?

Comment: What is `ctxCopy` and where does it come from? It's missing from your sourcecode.

Comment: What's the reason for creating the temporary image? You can use `drawImage` with another canvas as the source-parameter.

Comment: hey, sorry.
here is the complete script (assets/js/app.js)
http://comicedu.com/htmlcropper/v2/

please try to upload your image, then your image will be applied to the canvas and then you can draw in the canvas which i expect can copy the source to the result canvas (at the bottom)

Answer (score 0):

Your `ctxCopy` does not seem to be defined; you probably intend to do this:

```
var tmpCtx = tmpCanvas.getContext("2d");
...
tmpImageEl.onload = function(){
    tmpCtx.drawImage(this, x, y);    /// for your temporary canvas
    //ctxCopy.drawImage(this, x, y);    
}
```

There is also an issue in Chrome with data-uris as source; you can get around that by setting first an empty string, then the data-uri:

```
tmpImageEl.src = '';
tmpImageEl.src = tmpCanvas.toDataURL();
```

However, you can save yourselves a bit of trouble by simply using the `drawImage()` method *directly* on your temporary canvas to draw in the source canvas (it can take image, canvas and video as source input):

```
var tmpCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
tmpCanvas.width = tmpCanvas.height = 20;
var tmpCtx = tmpCanvas.getContext("2d");

tmpCtx.drawImage(ctx.canvas, 0, 0);
```

No need for `getPixelData()`/`putImageData()`/`image`, and it's much faster this way.

Hope this helps.

Comment: please try this http://comicedu.com/htmlcropper/v2/ and upload your own image, then drag your mouse inside the canvas